# Open directly ViewController of App from Safari

Tags: ios

I have 2 ViewController like so:

[image]

I want to open my app from safari by using URL Scheme, and I've already set it like this.

[image]

It worked when I open Safari and call: TestSafari://. But I want to it automatically open the ViewController2 instead of the initial ViewController, how to do this?

**Update**:

After setting like this in AppDelegate, it works well now.

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, handleOpenURL url: NSURL) -> Bool {
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VC2")
        self.window?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Custom url method in AppDelegate see reference here [Custom URL](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html)

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    MyViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [navController presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

    return YES;        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override this method in the Appdelegate.m file to handle the url

```js
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url     sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{
    //jump to view controll 2
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call your schema URL you can add some tags 
example : 
TestSafari://firstController
TestSafari://secondController

then you handle this in appDelegate :

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options{
if ([url.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"TestSafari://firstController"]) {
    //PresentYour first Controller;
}
else if ([url.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"TestSafari://secondController"]){
    // present your second contoller
}
return YES;
}
```

let me know if this help you :)

Comment: It should func application(application: UIApplication, handleOpenURL url: NSURL) :)

Comment: sorry i thought it was in Obj-C . thanks khuong291 :)